# Access external webAPI with C# (library \ code)

Tags: c#, web-services, dotnet-httpclient, webapi

**Background**

> We need to come up with a console app which will access an external
> webAPI and interact with another legacy system lets say in form of "input
> request files" and "output response files".
>
> So, we're looking to develop a C#
> console app to  handle all the complexity. It'll be supplied with request parameters. It shud be capable to handle any sort of Http Request config (headers, payload, security, ...)

**Before** creating anything from scratch using the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) class we're open to review existing library(if any). Don't want to re-invent the wheel (unless the extensive config of Http Request demands it).

There're a lot of online references but we need help in making the decision for the above scenario -

1. Use an existing **generic webAPI library** so coding is limited to boilerplate (like [AKSoftware](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consume-any-web-api-from-within-your-c-sharp-applications-using-aksoftware-webapi-lli/) - TBR) or
2. Use **start from scratch with existing HttpClient** class and build a wrapper to simplify webAPI access ([example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-api-using-httpclient/))

To clarify, this is NOT about developing webAPI but consuming existing popular webAPIs including Amazon MWS (lib exists), MIRAKL, etc...(diff webAPIs will demand different config & scalability measures). I'm sure such decisions have already been taken. Pls share your approach/inputs.

Comment: Trouble is, stackoverflow doesn't cater for questions that are answered with "expert opinions" - opinion based answers (and the questions that garner them) are specifically off topic here

Comment: I think you need to simplify your question a bit, but if I understand correctly, want to create a console app that can talk to existing web API's and also with a legacy system?   Specifically for MWS, you can download that MWS client for C#, add a reference to it from your new console app, and then call in to the MWS library as needed.  You don't need any raw HttpClient calls.  But I think you should edit your question for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks @ScottG I've tried to simplify as you asked. Yes, MWS has libraries which made us think if we can develop such lib for other APIs as well and create a simple console app to handle everything in background.